# trying to solve a C++ example and getting empty output

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and programming in general. I'm Trying to write this program 
[image: The Program im trying to write.]

This is the first stages of the program when i try to run it it and put R it instantly go to else it does not read if

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    double x, y;
    double cost;
    char frt;
    char Frcr;
    char crow;
    char R , r, F , f ;
    int yes = 0, Yes = 0, No = 0, no = 0;
    cout << "Please Enter length and Width of the picture in Inches :\n";
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << "Please Enter the Type of the Frame (R/F)(R Stands for Regular ,F Stands for Fancy) : \n";
    cin >> frt;


    if ('frt' == 'r' || 'frt' == 'R')
    {
        cost = (x + y)*0.15;
        cout << "Do you want to color the frame? (Yes/No) : \n";
        cin >> Frcr;

        if ('frcr' == yes || 'frcr' == Yes)
        {
            cost = (x + y)*0.15;
            cout << "The Cost is : " << (x + y)*0.15 + ((x + y)*0.10) << endl;
        }


        else if ('frcr' == no || 'frcr' == No)
        {
            cost = ((x + y)*0.15);
            cout << "The Cost Is : " << cost << endl;
        }



    }
    else
        cout << "There is an Error " << endl;
}
```

EDIT : Working Code after the help from the guys :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    double x, z;
    double cost;
    char frt;
    char Frcr;
    int Crow;
    int R, r, F, f;
    int y, Y, N, n;
    cout << "Please Enter The Width of the picture in Inches :";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please Enter The length of the picture in Inches :";

    cin >> z;
    cout << "Please Enter the Type of the Frame (R/F):" << endl;
    cout << "(R Stands for Regular ,F Stands for Fancy) \n";
    cin >> frt;



    if (frt == 'r' || frt == 'R')
    {
        cost = (x + z)*0.15;




        cout << "Do you want to color the frame? (Y/N) : \n";
        cin >> Frcr;
        if (Frcr == 'y' || Frcr == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Type The Number Of The Crowns You Want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The cost With Frame Coloring : " << ((x + z)*0.15) + ((x + z)*0.10) + (Crow*0.35) << endl;



        }
        else if (Frcr == 'N' || Frcr == 'n')
        {
            cout << "Type The Number Of The Crowns You Want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The Cost is : " << ((x + z)*0.15) + (Crow*0.35) << endl;

        }
        else
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;


    }
    else if (frt == 'f' || frt == 'F')
    {

        cout << "Do you want to color the frame? (Y/N) : \n";
        cin >> Frcr;

        if (Frcr == 'y' || Frcr == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Type The Number Of The Crowns You Want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The cost With Frame Coloring : " << ((x + z)*0.25) + ((x + z)*0.10) + (Crow*0.35) << endl;



        }
        else if (Frcr == 'N' || Frcr == 'n')
        {

            cout << "Type The Number Of The Crowns You Want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The Cost is : " << ((x + z)*0.25) + (Crow*0.35) << endl;

        }

        else
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;


    }


    else
        cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;



}
```

Comment: This is totally wrong ` if ('frt' == 'r' || 'frt' == 'R')` It should be ` if (frt == 'r' || frt == 'R')`. Same applies to all if statements

Comment: Oh Thank you so much :D

Comment: You have a bunch of other problems. You declare a bunch of variable you never use, like `F` and `r`. You ask for Yes/No` answers, but only input a single character, not a whole line.

Comment: You seem to have a general misunderstanding of the difference between variables, characters, and strings. I think you need to go back to the textbook and review those sections.

Comment: For instance, you set all these variables to the same thing: `yes = 0, Yes = 0, No = 0, no = 0;`, and then you compare the user's input to each of them. But if the user enters `y`, `frcr` will contain `121`, the ASCII code for the letter, not `0`.

Comment: @Barmar Do you have a website where i can find a good info about variables , chars and strings?

Comment: I removed the yes = 0, Yes = 0, No = 0, no = 0; and replaced it with yes,Yes,No,no;

Comment: Just `yes,Yes,No,no;` floating around is more wrong.

Comment: @Bashar I don't think they would be covered specifically in any website. They're basic concepts that are part of programming, and should be covered early on in any programming textbook or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This `'frt' == 'r'` is wrong. `frt`, `fcrcr` are both variables. Remove the ' '. It should be:

```
frt == 'r'
```

This `'frcr' == yes` is also wrong for many reasons. `frcr` is also a variable so again remove the ' '. Even then you can't do `frcr == "yes"` Instead:

1) Change `frcr` to `std::string` or 
2) keep the `char` and change `"yes"` to `'y'` or `'Y'`.

EDIT: Your code is just wrong in many ways. I suggest you to start with the basics. You need to learn.

Comment: this is my first week of c++ xD

Comment: Start reading the basics. Variables, data types, basic c++ syntax, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Final working code. Thank you guys for the help its working fine now :)
Please let me know if it is not the same as the image

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    double x, z;
    double cost;
    char frt;
    char Frcr;
    int Crow;
    int R , r, F , f ;
    int y , Y , N , n;
    cout << "Please Enter The Width of the picture in Inches :";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please Enter The length of the picture in Inches :";

    cin >> z;
    cout << "Please Enter the Type of the Frame (R/F)(R Stands for Regular ,F Stands for Fancy) : \n";
    cin >> frt;



    if (frt == 'r' || frt == 'R')
    {
        cost = (x + z)*0.15;




        cout << "Do you want to color the frame? (Y/N) : \n";
        cin >> Frcr;
        if (Frcr == 'y' || Frcr == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Type The number of the crowns you want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The cost With Frame Coloring : " << ((x + z)*0.15) + ((x + z)*0.10)+(Crow*0.35) << endl;



        }
        else if (Frcr == 'N' || Frcr == 'n')
        {
            cout << "Type The number of the crowns you want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The Cost is : " << ((x + z)*0.15) + (Crow*0.35) << endl;

        }
        else
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;


    }
    else if (frt == 'f' || frt == 'F')
    {

        cout << "Do you want to color the frame? (Y/N) : \n";
        cin >> Frcr;

        if (Frcr == 'y' || Frcr == 'Y')
        {
            cout << "Type The number of the crowns you want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The cost With Frame Coloring : " << ((x + z)*0.25) + ((x + z)*0.10)+(Crow*0.35) << endl;



        }
        else if (Frcr == 'N' || Frcr == 'n')
        {

            cout << "Type The number of the crowns you want ? :";
            cin >> Crow;
            cout << "The Cost is : " << ((x + z)*0.25) + (Crow*0.35) << endl;

        }

        else
            cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;


    }


    else
        cout << "Invalid Input." << endl;



    }
```